# Must I use Google play billing library if i want to sell an ad space directly to advertisers?

Tags: google-play-services, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I want to sell an ad space in my Android app that's on play store. I want to sell it directly to advertisers who will need to pick the target for their ads, Is it a must to use google play billing library to get payed for the adspace or i will be violating google play terms if i use another payment system. I went through this article  https://play.google.com/about/monetization-ads/payments/ unfortunately it was not clear to me. Any help please.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer support question, not a question about programming.

Comment: You're right @TylerH. But i asked this question to the customer support and they gave the link above in the question to go through. In my case the it's not so clear. Please help me so that i don't end up loosing my App from playstore by doing something I'm not sure of.

Comment: If there was something unclear, then the customer support that pointed you there would be the best people to provide clarification on your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, Google Play Billing Library only supports selling digital goods and click-based ads.

What you're looking for is Google Banner Ads https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner.

Comment: No I'm not looking for something like admob. I want to create my own custom layout and sell ad space directly to advertisers. I don't want to use Google play billing library. Will i be violating any terms of service if i use another third party mechanism to charge my clients?